# Why can't I add a new bank account for my App Store Connect?

Tags: ios, apple-developer, app-store-connect

I'm trying to replace the bank account info for my App Store Connect. However when I go to the **Agreements, Tax and Banking section**, I can only view and do some minor changes to my existing bank account info but there's no way to add a new bank account. I can confirm my Apple ID is an agent with Admin and Legal roles.

[image: Agreement, Tax and Banking page]

May I know where do I actually add a new bank account?

Comment: There is no automated process to change or add bank accounts.   Click "Contact Us" at the bottom of the screen and submit a request to the finance support team.

Comment: Did you update the current bank account type?

Comment: @KelvinTan I just did, and now I can only view the bank details but not able to edit anymore. Anyway this doesn't solve the main problem.

Comment: @Paulw11 I can't believe that's the only way to change bank accounts. :(

Comment: I guess it isn’t something you do very often and Apple wants it to be secure; Some accounts would have millions of dollars going through them.

Comment: Apple keeps updating the applestore connect's interface. I guess they will fix this issue in the future. If you need to replace the bank info now, you need to contact them for help.

Comment: I have only had to change my banking details once in 7 years, and that was about 2 years ago.  It was a support request then, as it is now.  I don't think they will ever change this.

Answer (score 84):

In App Store Connect, try Agreements -> Paid Applications -> Bank Accounts -> Edit. I see some options there, including "Replace with New Account".

Comment: This worked for me - I can add/change bank accounts from here (although I haven't gone through with it yet). It's worth noting that "Paid Applications" is under the Type column and looks like a piece of plain text, but it's clickable. Terrible discoverability all round.

Comment: Crazy! So you cannot change the bank account by navigating to Bank Accounts, but only via the method mentioned by Adrian on 5th Feb 2019. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to change only my Bank Address. I could not do, because all the other information was the same.

I contacted **Apple** and they called me after a few minutes. I explained the issue, and they asked me to try again. It worked.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Agreement, tax and Banking tab.
-> then -> Paid Apps -> Bank Accounts
There will be a edit option.

N.B: I am not sure some portion of the months might be edit option disable.